# HAProxy load balancing based on source ip (IP subnet)

Tags: routing, load-balancing, haproxy

I have x cluster. This cluster look like

```
Cluster 1
192.168.1. (Server type 1)
192.168.2. (Server type 2)
192.168.3.1 (Server type 3) <Redis server> 

Cluster 2
192.167.1. (Server type 1)
192.167.2. (Server type 2)
192.167.3.1 (Server type 3) <Redis server>
```

Currently I am managing cluster group configuration in code. Is it possible to have a domain called as  using haproxy And which redirect require based on source ip? For example

```
192.167.* request gets redirect to 192.167.3.1
```

and

```
192.168.* request gets redirect to 192.168.3.1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is possible with [HAProxy ACLs](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/haproxy-configuration-tutorials/core-concepts/acls/). You need to setup 2 backends, one for each block, then in the frontend create 2 acls, one for each backend.

Your frontend block would look something like this

```
   acl block_7 src 192.167.0.0/16
   acl block_8 src 192.168.0.0/16

   use_backend block_7_hosts if block_7 
   use_backend block_8_hosts if block_8
```

Then define a backends `block_7_hosts` and `block_8_hosts` with the correct redis server in them.

If you don't plan on adding more Redis servers though you may just want to use a configuration management tool since you aren't really load balancing.

Comment: ya I want to do static routing and distribute load manually

Comment: `use_backend` :)