# Postfix TLS policy based on source IP

Tags: ssl, postfix

I have an old MTA, that effectively cannot do anything TLS related.

It is being used for a number of internal systems, of which a subset of them have stricter requirements, where they must only send mail, if the receiver is able to recive using TLS; the policy 'must'.

I would like to implement a scenario where I replace that MTA with a Postfix drop-in replacement on same IP, as the systems are not easily configurable.

I'd like to hear if it is possible to say that server A,B,C,D (based on IP address/hostname etc) can send using 'may' policy, but server E,F should use the 'must' policy, regardless of the destinations.

I can find a lot of information on smtp-tls-policy-maps that handles this pr. destination, but nothing based on 'pr-source'.

Can anyone hint to as if it's possible, and where I should look in the docs?

If not, can anyone point to another product where this might be possible?

Br, Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature of the current release of postfix.

---

You could perhaps do what you want with 2 postfix servers, one set for `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt` and one set for `smtp_tls_security_level = may`, and haproxy using [haproxy ACLs](https://serverfault.com/a/502581/) to direct the clients to the appropriate server.

---

With tools like `ansible` or `expect` the realm of what is difficult to configure can rapidly shrink. The first time: nigh impossible; subsequently: trivial.