# enforce TLS on outgoing mail in postfix

Tags: postfix

I want to enable mandatory TLS encryption on outgoing mail for some (not all) domains.

I solved it for **incoming** mail if I set:

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

and in `tls_policy`

```
example.com encrypt
```

All connections from the receiving domain example.com are over TLS.

How can I enforce this for **outgoing** mail for some domains?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at TLS Policy Maps feature. It is designed for that specific scenario. It allows you to specify 'may' or 'must' to separate domains; like this:

```
example.net           secure  match=example.net:.example.net
anotherexample.net    may     match=anotherexample.com:.anotherexample.com
```

Read more about it here:

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps

Comment: In the documation it says 'The TLS policy table is indexed by the full next-hop destination, which is either the RECIPIENT domain ... '. But I want to enforce smtp by SENDING domain.

Comment: Ah; how interesting; I've had almost the same wish. In short; you can't. It appears, that most rule handling is destination based; see https://serverfault.com/questions/910522/postfix-tls-policy-based-on-source-ip/ which I raised. :-) If you have another MTA that can route based on source domain, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a combination of [`smtpd_tls_received_header`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_received_header) and [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#header_checks).

---

The following is a quick *untested* example, and may not be entirely suitable, but it might serve as a useful starting point. It's advisable to start with a `WARN` or `INFO` action for testing.
It's also possible given the multiline nature of the attempted match that `nested_header_check` is more suitable than `header_checks`.

`main.cf`

```
header_checks = pcre:$config_directory/smtpd_tls
```

`smtpd_tls`

```
if /Return-Path:.+<.+@(example\.com)>/
!/Received: from ([^ ]+) \([^\)]+) +
 \(using [^ ] with cipher [^ ]+ [^(]+\)\)
 +[^(]+\)
 +by mx1\.example\.net/x
   REJECT mail from $1 must be sent using TLS
endif
```

This is intended to match all mail from example.com and reject it if it doesn't contain a pattern similar to:

```
Received: from smtp.example.com (smtp.example.com  [192.0.2.1])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by mx1.example.com
```

Comment: @rubo77 @sysadmin1138 I will note that `smtp` which is what the author claims to have solved apply to *outgoing* messages while `smtpd` applies to incoming. So the stated solution works for outgoing and not incoming. See also the comment on the other answer where it is strongly implied that the sending domain is sending to the author, i.e. is incoming mail, at least as most people would understand it.